# How to darken background when hovering on image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a jQuery hover button. When you hover over the box, a jQuery button appears. However, it doesn't work. Can someone show me how to add a black background to the box when hovered over?

The objective is to;

1. When rolling over the box, it displays "chart it btn"
2. When rolling over the box, the box gets a black background.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7pw8E/7/)

```
/*  CHART IT BTN ON POTS
===================================================================*/
$(".btn-trigger").hover(function () {
    $(this).find(".charthis-btn").show();
}, function () {
    $(this).find(".charthis-btn").hide();
})
```

I need the image that is shown to darken black with an opacity of 50% when rolled over.

Comment: @PaulDesigner Are you looking to make the button stick and the background of the button black? Or the button stick and the background of the form black?

Comment: blue btn to show on hover with a black bg

Comment: So something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Agony/7pw8E/6/

Comment: Please see updated fiddle ..I need the image shown to darken black with an opacity of 50% when rolled over. I look forward to your reply. jsfiddle.net/7pw8E/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's what you want but try this:

**EDIT**

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7pw8E/8/)

```
$(".display-box").hover(function () {
    $(this).find(".charthis-btn").show();
    $(this).find(".hover-mask").fadeIn();
}, function () {
    $(this).find(".charthis-btn").hide();
    $(this).find(".hover-mask").fadeOut();
})
```

Comment: I have updated my fiddle so I can explain the objective more clear. I need the image shown to darken black with an opacity of 50% when rolled over. I look forward to your reply. jsfiddle.net/7pw8E/7

Answer (score 1):

The [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7pw8E/4/)

JS :

```
$(".display-box").hover(function () {
$(this).find(".charthis-btn").show();
}, function () {
$(this).find(".charthis-btn").hide();
})
```

Comment: hi, Thanks for your help. I have updated my fiddle so I can explain the objective more clear. I need the image shown to darken black with an opacity of 50% when rolled over. I look forward to your reply. http://jsfiddle.net/7pw8E/7/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".display-box").hover(function () {
$(this).find(".charthis-btn").show();
}, function () {
$(this).find(".charthis-btn").hide();
})
$(".charthis-btn").on('mouseenter',function(){
$(".display-box img").css('opacity','0.5');
})
$(".charthis-btn").on('mouseout',function(){
$(".display-box img").css('opacity','');
})
```

Comment: hi, Thanks for your help. I have updated my fiddle so I can explain the objective more clear. I need the image shown to darken black with an opacity of 50% when rolled over. I look forward to your reply. jsfiddle.net/7pw8E/7